# I am trying to find why my programs gives me zeros for both areas

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <math.h>
    double areaTriangle(double sideA,double sideB,double sideC);
    double periTriangle(double sideA,double sideB,double sideC);
    
    int main (void){
     double side1A,side1B,side1C;
      double side2A,side2B,side2C;
      double area1, area2;
        printf("Enter the side for the first triangle: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&side1A,&side1B,&side1C);
        printf("\nEnter the sides for the second triangle: ");
        scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&side2A,&side2B,&side2C);
        area1=areaTriangle(side1A,side1B,side1C);
        area2=areaTriangle(side2A,side2B,side2C);
        printf("Area 1 is %lf and Area 2 is %f",area1,area2);
        return 0;
    
    }
    double areaTriangle(double sideA,double sideB,double sideC){
        double area=0;
        periTriangle(sideA,sideB,sideC);
        sqrt(periTriangle*(periTriangle-sideA)*(periTriangle-sideB)*(periTriangle-sideC);
    }
    double periTriangle(double sideA,double sideB,double sideC){
            periTriangle=(sideA+sideB+sideC)/3;
            return periTriangle;
        }
```

So when I type in any values for any of the triangles I get zero no what I do. For example, I input 10 for all sides in both triangles and all I get is:  Area 1 is 0.000000 and Area 2 is 0.000000. Why tho?

Comment: areaTriangle doesn't return anything, and it doesn't use the return value of periTriangle. Be sure you have compiler warnings on, it will catch things like that.

Comment: There's no way that code compiles at all on any sane compiler.

Comment: @BlazeWinger This statement sqrt(periTriangle*(periTriangle-sideA)*(periTriangle-sideB)*(periTriangle-sideC); does not make a sense.

Comment: it's conforming i think, add -Wall -Wextra when compiling tho

Comment: @wojand: you can't subtract a double from a pointer, let alone a function pointer

Answer (score 1):

`periTriangle(sideA,sideB,sideC);`
does not save the return value;

It could be `double peri = periTriangle(sideA,sideB,sideC);`
(and below that use peri where you used periTriangle)
Also, the parens don't match where you call sqrt.

Also, I think you should divide by 2, not 3 in periTriangle, no?

[Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) for Area of a Triangle with three sides known.

Comment: also, return the result  of sqrt:

Comment: `return sqrt(.....);`